# routing all module traffic to default module in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, module, routes

I'm looking to forward all of my requests from :

.com/m/

to

.com/

I thought I could try to do this in the module's bootstrap, but the front controller isn't setup just yet.  I keep seeing mentions of front controller plugins, but how would I set it up just for this module?

Sorry for the dumb questions, I'm still trying to get a grasp on the Zend Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a controller plugin that routes all traffic to a specific module to the default module.  I give 2 ways to route the traffic, either by forwarding the request (url stays the same but executes default module), or by then redirecting the browser to the default module.

Note, this is untested but should work.  Let me know if you have questions or problems with it.

```
<?php

class Application_Plugin_ModuleRedirector extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $module     = $request->getModuleName();
        $controller = $request->getControllerName();
        $action     = $request->getActionName();

        // don't execute plugin if not in the module "m"
        if ($module != 'm') {
            return ;
        }

        // foward to default module with same controller and action
        $request->setModuleName('default')
                ->setControllerName($controller)
                ->setActionName($action);

        // OR remove the above and use this for a hard redirect
        $urlHelper  = new Zend_View_Helper_Url();
        $url        = $urlHelper->url(array(
                                       'module' => 'default',
                                       'controller' => $controller,
                                       'action'     => $action));

        $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::
                      getStaticHelper('redirector');

        $redirector->gotoUrl($url);
    }
}
```

To activate it, register the plugin with the Front Controller:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_ModuleRedirector());
```

Comment: I was excited to see your answer, and for simple URLs, this works as advertised... but then I ran into all of my fancy routing and for some reason, this code does not recognize the module where values in the URL are variables...  :(

Comment: What's an example of one of the URLs where it doesn't work?  preDispatch plugins run after the URL has been decomposed for routing so is it possible those more complex URLs are not being routed correctly based on routes you have defined?